# Regular expressions that find all words that meet a condition

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I'm trying to work out the exercise from a book called *R for Data Science* on regular expressions.

There's this question which I'm unable to solve :

- Given the corpus of common words in `stringr::words`, create regular expressions that find all words that:

  1. Start with “y”.
  2. End with “x”
  3. Have seven letters or more.

Example:

```
sentence <- "I want to extract these - yandx,ynx and yrax,romanav "

# it would be helpful to find how to do these with stringr::str_view() function.
```

Also, please refer me to some good resources for learning regex in R.

Comment: `stringr::str_extract_all(sentence, '\\by\\w{7,}x\\b')`, but you don't have any words that meet all three conditions.

Comment: I would probably start with `help(regex)`

Comment: Is it possible to do it just by making use of  "  ^  ,  $ , \\ ,  .  "

Comment: @alistaire perhaps is "seven letters or less"?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I think it might be three separate tasks, or maybe it's an "or"/`any` instead of "and"/`all` relation, e.g. `stringr::str_extract_all(sentence, '\\by\\w*|\\w*x\\b|\\w{7,}')`

Answer (score 0):

This regex should work for you (considering your words don't contain punctuation)

```
(?i)((?:^y[a-z]+x)|(?:^[a-z]{7}[a-z]*$))
```

Also you can use [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) to validate your regex

Comment: What is this regex supposed to be doing?

Comment: Extract words that start with Y and ends with X (case insensitive) or is of 7 or more letters

Comment: That is not what this does.  Check on `stringr::words`